# How do I set Ubuntu as the default OS for Chromebox/Chrome OS?

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, chromebook, chromeos

I installed ubuntu-desktop lts (14.04) on my [intel Asus Chromebox](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IT1WJZQ) using the script at: http://goo.gl/9sgchs. Everything is working great when I manually boot into Ubuntu (i.e. pressing ctrl-L at the dev mode screen). However, I am not able to automatically boot into Ubuntu upon restart; the system always boots into Chrome OS unless I press ctrl-L at the boot screen. I tried the command `sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S 1 /dev/sda` a few times in both Ubuntu terminal and Chrome OS bash to try to set the boot priority, but it seems to just ignore this and boot into Chrome OS anyway (no error messages either). How can I set Ubuntu as the default OS?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after a few hours of googling - here are the details for anyone that might run into a similar problem:

1.) Remove the firmware write-protect screw inside the Chromebox as shown in the picture [here](http://www.deconetworks.com/chromebox-full-linux-desktop/) (requires a screwdriver and opening of the case).

2.) Follow the instructions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chrome_OS_devices#Boot_to_SeaBIOS_by_default) under the section "Boot to SeaBIOS by default".

Essentially, once the write-protect screw is removed, the commands (in Chrome OS shell) are:

```
sudo su
flashrom --wp-disable
flashrom --wp-status
/usr/share/vboot/bin/set_gbb_flags.sh
/usr/share/vboot/bin/set_gbb_flags.sh 0x489
flashrom --wp-enable
```

Some of the above commands might just be informational, I think the wp-status one and the first .sh command, but not totally sure.